# Using OpenCV in Xcode project gives linker errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, opencv

After building and installing opencv via their cmake process, I took some suggested steps to integrate the libraries into an Xcode project.

- I use "Link Binary With Libraries" in Build Phases for both libopencv_core.dylib and libopencv_highgui.dylib
- "Header Search Paths" contains /usr/local/include/ and /usr/include/ (the opencv headers themselves are in /usr/local/include/opencv2, which I have tried to include)
- "Library Search Paths" contains /usr/local/lib and /usr/lib (the opencv dylib files are in /usr/local/lib/)

And then I added a bit of demo opencv code. When I run this project, I get errors you'd expect from a linking problem:

`Apple Mach-O Linker Error:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvCvtColor", referenced from:`

Using `file` on the dylibs I include shows what I expect:

`file /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`

`file /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib 
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`

Both of these files are built for the proper architecture and (I think) properly added to the project. How can I debug other linker issues that I might be having? Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cvtColor` is in libopencv_imgproc.dylib. Add that to the "Link Binary with Libraries" phase and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks! I think I read somewhere that I only had to include core and highgui, and that advice was obviously not meant for the project I was building.

Comment: [The wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port) says _Select libopencv_core.dylib, libopencv_highgui.dylib, and any other libraries required by your project_. The [OpenCV Documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/) will tell you which library contains the function you're using.